# longtable extends unnecessarily to a second page

Tags: longtable, datatool

The following code displays what I think is a minor but annoying bug.
The longtable shown extends to the second page, but there are no columns on the second page, so it is unnecessary to extend the longtable to the second page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[verbose]{datatool}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\newcommand{\PrintTable}[2]{%
 % #1 = database
 % #2 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{c}
    \caption{#2}\\
    Col\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    {#1}{%
      \Col=Col%
    }{%
      \Col \\
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.csv}
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
  foo,
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{./foo.csv}{
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Col,}]{DB}{foo.csv}
\PrintTable{DB}{Foo}
}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can reproduce, please comment. Thanks.

Comment: I have two raws in 2 nd page so it's necessary

Comment: @touhami I don't follow.

Comment: you longtable is one column but several raws (lines) if i compile it i get 2 raws in 2 nd page.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I get no rows on the second page. Try removing two rows from the csv file.

Comment: I removed one i get one page.

Comment: @touhami Hmm. Discouraging. Can anyone else reproduce?

Comment: That's a lot of empty space. I should probably combine those PNGs into one.

Comment: If you can't reproduce, try taking out `letter` from the first line and/or replacing with `a4paper`.

Comment: Why? What code shows the problem for you? Do you need to change things to make the problem appear?

Comment: I can reproduce. `letter` is not a proper option. I'm betting your default paper size is set to A4, though. You want `letterpaper`, I think, and `geometry`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I get exactly the image you show, is this problematic? I thing this is what longtable build for.

Comment: @touhami Yes, an unnecessary blank row which goes to the next page is problematic, though it's a relatively minor issue. But still annoying.

Comment: @cfr I've corrected `letter` to `letterpaper`. Is it Ok now? I can reproduce the issue with both `a4paper` and `letterpaper` options, but I need to use a different number of rows for the two options. I don't know what you mean by the reference to `geometry`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are ending every row with `\\` inside the `\DTLforeach`. This means that you are executing code after the final `\\` and such code can easily lead to an empty row at the end of the tabular. You can visualize the problem by using a preamble like `{>{blub}c}`. I suggest moving the `\\` to the beginning, and suppressing the first `\\` with `\DTLiffirstrow`:

```
\newcommand{\PrintTable}[2]{%
 % #1 = database
 % #2 =caption
  \begin{longtable}{>{blub}c}
    \caption{#2}\\
    Col\\\hline\endhead
    \DTLforeach
    {#1}{%
      \Col=Col%
    }{%
     \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}%
     \Col
    }%
  \end{longtable}
}%
```

Comment: Yes, I see. The `blub` executes at the beginning of every line, including the blank line. But if I don't have anything except the `{c}`, is there any code that is executed? In any case, the change you suggested fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The blub only shows that there is a row, it doesn't create it. The row is created by the datatool command. Only because a row *looks* empty it doesn't mean that nothing is it. A command like \relax will create a row.

Comment: Ok. But if I don't specifically add any commands, are there still commands that will be executed in this case? E.g. `\relax`? Or, to put it another way, is there some way of determining which commands *are* in fact being executed in this case?

Comment: Obviously there are commands: After all you are getting an unwanted row as shown in your question. The commands are from end code of \DTLforeach. You can only avoid it by making sure that \DTLforeach completes its works before the last \\.

Comment: Ok, understood.