# Longtable starts a second page to print only the \bottomrule line

Tags: longtable, booktabs

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

a

b

c

d

e

f

g


\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!6}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\caption{\label{tab:unnamed-chunk-1}My table}\\
\hiderowcolors
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{My table \textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb\\
\midrule
\endhead
\showrowcolors
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4\\
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108.0 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258.0 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215 & 19.44 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360.0 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440 & 17.02 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\addlinespace
Valiant & 18.1 & 6 & 225.0 & 105 & 2.76 & 3.460 & 20.22 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Duster 360 & 14.3 & 8 & 360.0 & 245 & 3.21 & 3.570 & 15.84 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Merc 240D & 24.4 & 4 & 146.7 & 62 & 3.69 & 3.190 & 20.00 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
Merc 230 & 22.8 & 4 & 140.8 & 95 & 3.92 & 3.150 & 22.90 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
Merc 280 & 19.2 & 6 & 167.6 & 123 & 3.92 & 3.440 & 18.30 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 4\\
\addlinespace
Merc 280C & 17.8 & 6 & 167.6 & 123 & 3.92 & 3.440 & 18.90 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 4\\
Merc 450SE & 16.4 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 4.070 & 17.40 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Merc 450SL & 17.3 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 3.730 & 17.60 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Merc 450SLC & 15.2 & 8 & 275.8 & 180 & 3.07 & 3.780 & 18.00 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3\\
Cadillac Fleetwood & 10.4 & 8 & 472.0 & 205 & 2.93 & 5.250 & 17.98 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
\addlinespace
Lincoln Continental & 10.4 & 8 & 460.0 & 215 & 3.00 & 5.424 & 17.82 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Chrysler Imperial & 14.7 & 8 & 440.0 & 230 & 3.23 & 5.345 & 17.42 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Fiat 128 & 32.4 & 4 & 78.7 & 66 & 4.08 & 2.200 & 19.47 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Honda Civic & 30.4 & 4 & 75.7 & 52 & 4.93 & 1.615 & 18.52 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
Toyota Corolla & 33.9 & 4 & 71.1 & 65 & 4.22 & 1.835 & 19.90 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
\addlinespace
Toyota Corona & 21.5 & 4 & 120.1 & 97 & 3.70 & 2.465 & 20.01 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
Dodge Challenger & 15.5 & 8 & 318.0 & 150 & 2.76 & 3.520 & 16.87 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
AMC Javelin & 15.2 & 8 & 304.0 & 150 & 3.15 & 3.435 & 17.30 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
Camaro Z28 & 13.3 & 8 & 350.0 & 245 & 3.73 & 3.840 & 15.41 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
Pontiac Firebird & 19.2 & 8 & 400.0 & 175 & 3.08 & 3.845 & 17.05 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\addlinespace
Fiat X1-9 & 27.3 & 4 & 79.0 & 66 & 4.08 & 1.935 & 18.90 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1\\
Porsche 914-2 & 26.0 & 4 & 120.3 & 91 & 4.43 & 2.140 & 16.70 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 2\\
Lotus Europa & 30.4 & 4 & 95.1 & 113 & 3.77 & 1.513 & 16.90 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 2\\
Ford Pantera L & 15.8 & 8 & 351.0 & 264 & 4.22 & 3.170 & 14.50 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 4\\
Ferrari Dino & 19.7 & 6 & 145.0 & 175 & 3.62 & 2.770 & 15.50 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 6\\
\addlinespace
Maserati Bora & 15.0 & 8 & 301.0 & 335 & 3.54 & 3.570 & 14.60 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 8\\
Volvo 142E & 21.4 & 4 & 121.0 & 109 & 4.11 & 2.780 & 18.60 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}

\end{document}
```

And in the output, the second caption appears on the second page, while there's no more row to show:

[image]

In fact there's the line generated by `\bottomrule` on the second page. Can we prevent that?

(Similar but not identical issue: [longtable extends unnecessarily to a second page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302332/longtable-extends-unnecessarily-to-a-second-page))

Comment: Use it as foot (bottomrule). Then it should not be separated.

Comment: @TeXnician You mean using `\endfoot`? Could you give more details please? I don't master `longtable`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - Wht TeXnician is suggesting is to (a) delete the `bottomrule` directive from the *body* of the table and (b) provide the instructions `\bottomrule\endfoot` immediately after `\endhead`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Use `\bottomrule\endfoot`. And remove the last `\bottomrule` (keep the `\\ `).

Comment: Mico & @TeXnician, yes it works. Thanks. This looks like an answer to be accepted...

Comment: You can use `\\*\bottomrule` to prevent the pagebreak between the rule and the previous line. But in this case imho setting the rule with \endfoot is probably more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize longtable's mechanisms. It will always keep the footer (which a bottomrule belongs to) adjacent to the row. So a solution uses the footer mechanism.

The following code should be added directly after `\endhead`:

```
\bottomrule\endfoot
```

Just a note (comment by Bernard): You may want to use `\endlastfoot`. That would only affect the very end of the table, whereas `\endfoot` affects also every break.

Then remove the `\bottomrule` from the document body, but keep `\\`.

Comment: Maybe `\endlastfoot` only, given the table?

Comment: @Bernard You may be right. I'll add a note.

Comment: Thanks TeXnician. That doesn't work with `\endlastfoot` instead of `\endfoot`. Am I missing something ?